# Caching RSS plugin data

Tags: plugins, cache

I'm developing plugin and I need it's data to be cached, let's assume that it's large RSS feed grabber. 
Basically data of one RSS feed is about 100 lines of parsed HTML code (about 2KB). On one page there can be from 1 to 5 RSS feeds.

My question is, what is the best to cache and store this? Should I use transients? Or just save data to custom created database table? Or create "RSS feed" custom post type?

Plugin data is not attached to post.

Thank you.